# Backpressure not being respected in chain with flatMap and multiple observeOn's

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I am not sure why backpressure is not being respected in this flowable chain.

I have simplified it to the following: There are 3 stages, `heavyFlowableBasedOnInput`, `singleThreadedPieceOfWork` and `writeFileToDisk`. The first 2 stages happen much faster than the final stage, so their output stays memory waiting for step 3, leading to out of memory error/ continuously increasing memory usage.

When I watch the debugger, I notice step 1 happening a lot more often than step 3, even though I have set the buffer size (third argument of observeOn) to a low number (e.g. 1).

```kotlin
Flowable.fromIterable(listOfResources)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap { flowableUsing(it) } // small flowable though, ~0-10, mostly 1 to 2 emissions
        .observeOn(Schedulers.single(), false, 1)
        .map { singleThreadedPieceOfWork() }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1)
        .map { writeFileToDisk() }
        .subscribe()
```

I have read the documentation for each operator I am using, it looks like all of them have some backpressure support (e.g. passing through backpressure `BackpressureKind.PASS_THROUGH`, honours downstream backpressure `BackpressureKind.FULL`). I have no clues as to why I am overloading the  queue/ buffer for writeFileToDisk.

I did read [Why doesn't my RxJava Flowable respect backpressure when using observeOn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176982/why-doesnt-my-rxjava-flowable-respect-backpressure-when-using-observeon) I understand that observeOn creates an "asynchronous boundary", but I don't know how this affects backpressure.

### An image of memory usage going up steadily

[image: Memory profile from Android Studio]

Comment: I tried to simplify the chain, but didn't want to remove important details: e.g. 2 observeOn's are being used, and a flatMap.

Comment: is this really java? Looks more like groovy.

Comment: Corrected it, its kotlin actually. I only added `rx-java` initially

Comment: I do not think you are having a problem with backpressure. Your memory plot clearly shows, that the native memory usage is quite high. It seems you are leaking native memory. I would suppose, that the issue is in not closing resources in `writeFileToDisk`.   Can you trace the native allocations of your application? Also 0.8 GiB graphics seems quite a lot. Looks like you are leaking memory somewhere. Use adb shell dumpsys meminfo <pid>|<packageName> and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

From [akarnokds](https://akarnokd.blogspot.com/2016/02/flatmap-part-1.html) blog:

> Backpressure, the way of preventing buffer-bloat with reactive flows,
> is a cornerstone of RxJava. Most operators that don't have timing
> aspects in them apply and honor backpressure. Unfortunately, flatMap
> by default can only say it honors backpressure but doesn't apply it
> towards its main input.
>
> This means that when you use the common overload of flatMap or merge,
> the operator will request Long.MAX_VALUE from its upstream and realize
> it all at once. This unbounded behavior leads to an unbounded number
> of active subscriptions to the generated inner Observables.
>
> This property doesn't cause much trouble if the inner Observables are
> short or infrequently emitting, but if there is an asynchronous
> boundary after flatMap, let's say, observeOn, items can quite easily
> pile up in flatMap and degrade performance considerably.

I **think** I fixed it by specifying the maxConcurrency parameter in the flatMap overloaded function:
kotlin

```
Flowable.fromIterable(listOfResources)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap({ flowableUsing(it) }, false, 1, 5) // <-- the maxConcurrency and bufferSize 
        .observeOn(Schedulers.single(), false, 1)
        .map { singleThreadedPieceOfWork() }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1)
        .map { writeFileToDisk() }
        .subscribe()
```

Alternatively, this wasn't a fix. I might have just reduced the performance so much that this memory issue doesn't occur anymore.

**Pending more reading/ understanding**